# How can I find reviewers for a (complexity theory) book I help editing?

Tags: discussion

I help editing a new edition of the [Gacs-Lovasz: Complexity of Algorithms](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/complexity.pdf) book. What is the best way to find some experienced people who would proofread some parts of it? E.g. is there a way to post ads here, for let's say reputation points?? Is this question already an ad??? Why are there more question marks at the end of each sentence????

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta ?????

Comment: The second question probably yes, but my main question is the first one, which probably fits the soft-question category, doesn't it?????? :) Nevertheless, I am happy to move it there, if you think it is more appropriate there.

Comment: I think [Academia.se] is more suitable for the question in the title. However questions about the site should be on [meta].

Comment: Another possibility, if you're so inclined, is the new Google+ TCS community

Comment: or you can start a blog and [ask there](http://andysresearch.blogspot.ca/2011/05/exciting-new-textbook-and-request.html) :)

Comment: There should be a wiki or forum where readers can submit line-by-line comments/edits on a TCS draft.  I would like to see the following features:  -authors can submit their pdfs to be proofread/commented on, and all such work should have the authors' consent;  -edits are typically named to show volunteer contributions;  -chapter-by-chapter, section-by-section divisions to make the contributions easier to use and to avoid reduplication of effort.

Comment: Hi domotorp, I've done some basic proofreading of Chaps. 1-4.  Will send to you.

Comment: Now looking at the comments, I think it is best to move the question to meta - can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: I migrated it to meta as you requested. However I agree with Andy. A site for reviewing combining something like arxiv with conference review software with some SE like features would be interesting.

Comment: Thx! So let me know if anyone knows about such a site...

Comment: strongly support the idea of a community/cyberspace review system but any such project would inherently be fraught with some political controversy. here is a list of ~100 papers still waiting to be reviewed by the community— [woeginger p vs np page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm). also one should study the dynamics of the deolalikar commotion of 2.5 yr ago, 4 good refs to that [here](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/outline-for-a-np-vsppoly-proof-based-on-monotone-circuits-hypergraphs-and-factoring/) along with "some other stuff" too =)

Comment: I would advocate that such a project be aimed principally at improving writeup quality and fixing typos/grammar, NOT at checking proofs of earth-shattering claims or deciding whether a paper is conference-worthy.  The main intended application would be refining textbook drafts.  I would be happy to see proofreaders make helpful suggestions about the content as well, but within a supportive, non-political framework.

Comment: actually it would be possible to launch a stackexchange group for this purpose if there were enough volunteers, & its infrastructure would provide a lot of useful/relevant features (votes to prioritize what to review, reputation to measure merit of reviews etc) but unf there would prob not be very many volunteers & it would be difficult to overcome the new group membership commitment/count threshhold. for anyone interested proposals for new groups go [here on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: more on community tcs reviewing idea on ["community brain"](http://windowsontheory.org/2012/07/16/community-brain-2/), windows on theory blog

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [nb](http://nb.mit.edu/welcome), developed by David Karger's group at MIT. The interface is very slick for online editing, and keeps track of edits and who made them.

Comment: This is a brilliant tool, thx! But the question still remains how to find proofreaders...

Comment: That's a much harder problem :). you might want to start with a few people and spread the word.

Comment: The answers show that the main question of the OP has nothing to do with [meta].

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be that posting your request on on [CS Theory Google+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102658328974323340942) would be quite appropriate, and you might find reviewers that way.